# Protecting PHP packages on server

Tags: security, .htaccess, soap, wsdl

I am a php developer and have recently decided to make one of my Magento extensions commercial. I have downloaded and configured [MageParts CEM Server](http://www.mageparts.com/products/c-e-m/mageparts-commercial-extension-manager-server.html) and that is all working perfectly in regard to licencing and delivery of module packages. The only issue is that the directory that the packages are stored in could be accessed by anyone. I tried this in a `.htaccess` file, but now it is not working.

```
<Files services.wsdl>
allow from all
</Files>

deny from all
```

Clients are receiving a `403 Forbidden` response. Have I done something wrong in the `.htaccess` file or would there be a better way to secure the directory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also use "Order Deny,Allow" directive. Apache's allow/deny directives a somewhat tricky to understand.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this but it made no difference. Would it be possible for you to post an example?

Comment: Order deny,allow
<Files services.wsdl>
    allow from all
</Files>
Deny from all

Comment: Thanks for the example but this is still producing the same error.

Comment: Just checked: http://pastebin.com/RyWS05iP

Comment: Looks a bit ugly. "Conflict" may be if "services.wsdl" is not really existing file. <Files> directive controls access to filesystem, so if it is rewrited to other filename you should allow access to that file or use <Location|LocationMatch> directives instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
deny from all

<Files services.wsdl>
    allow from all
</Files>
```

?

Comment: No luck with that either. Still the same 403 message.